# Having trouble centering image vertically in responsive website [in both PC and mobile]

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

Here is what I see for my website:

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcHIR.png)

As the image is below Navigation Bar, I want this to center vertically in my responsive website, similar to this website: https://www.ownhour.co.kr/#;

I have added width and height as 100% in internal image stylesheet and added margin and block in external CSS. After inspecting with the mobile version, it seems like the image is sitting at the top with a huge gap at the bottom.

Here is what I see for my website:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="monday.css">
    <title>J[a]son</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class = "logo">
            <h4>J[a]son</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class = "nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="photography_colour.html">Colour</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photography_black.html">Black</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CODING</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class= "burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
    <img class="main_car" src="Photos/main_car.jpg" alt="car" width="100%" height="100%"/>
           <!--<p>June, 2020. Sunshine Coast, BC, Canada </p>-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*padding-right: 2em;*/
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    /*font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    color: rgb(240, 235, 235);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    /*padding: 5px 5px;*/
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1430px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:950px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 30%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        padding-right: 2em;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
    .sub-menu {
        position: relative;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translate(0%);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the style you are using for wide screens and also enough HTML to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hello. I have just updated my HTML and CSS code. Appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is how to center the car image and remain responsive.

As I understand it (and this may need adjustment for your particular case) the requirement is for the car image to fill space but not leave a huge gap underneath before the footers are reached.

To do this in this case I've set the body element to flex so that once it's decided what is needed space-wise for the navbar and footer it can fill the remaining space with the car.

I initially tried to do this with `object-fit: contain` and `object-position: center` within a wrapper around the car img. However, I could not make this work and instead I've removed the car image and set it as a background to a div instead and allowed this div to fill up any remaining space on the screen.

Here's the snippet.

```css
    * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /*padding-right: 2em;*/
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    /*font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    color: rgb(240, 235, 235);
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    /*padding: 5px 5px;*/
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1430px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:950px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 30%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        padding-right: 2em;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 1em;
    }
    .sub-menu {
        position: relative;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translate(0%);https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png
}
.main_car_wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://ahweb.org.uk/car.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    }

    </style>
```

```html
<nav>
        <div class = "logo">
            <h4>J[a]son</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class = "nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="#">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="photography_colour.html">Colour</a></li>
                    <li><a href="photography_black.html">Black</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CODING</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class= "burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="testing.js"></script>
    <div class="main_car_wrapper">
    </div>
    And some more footer stuff here
           <p>June, 2020. Sunshine Coast, BC, Canada </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATED

Can use with code like

```
margin-left: -50px;
margin-right: -50px;
width:100px;
```

in

```
.main_car img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: [-50% of your image's width];
margin-top: [-50% of your image's height];
}
```

I'm added css like this

```
.main_car
{
position: relative;
}
.main_car img
{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: [-50% of your image's width];
margin-top: [-50% of your image's height];
}
```

Then will get output like this
**Centered Image**

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  /*rgb(241, 233, 233);*/
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.main_car
{
    position: relative;
}
.main_car img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    width:100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1430px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:950px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    padding-right: 2em;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    position: relaative;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main_car">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/efb780ba8c3560a06d4c1a1825b1e800?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="car">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited with your code and calculated the width and height to 50% of my image to pixel (480px and 233px), however, I'm still having the same issue where it won't vertically centre.

Comment: You can used `margin-right` for change a `margin-top`, see my updated

Comment: Thank you again for the updated version. Unfortunately, I have tried your code and does not work..:(